# como puedo sustraer unicamente el texto que valla seguido despues de una arroba

Tags: php

hola lo que quiero es que de una cadena de texto solo me aparezca lo que este pegado a una arroba (en php)
ejemplo:
hola @carlos como estas .. 
que solo aparezca 
@carlos 
Gracias , saludos

Comment: añade por favor que has intentado

Comment: haz un split con el caracter @, y sabes que en la posicion 1 del array tienes lo que va después. Si luego quieres algo concreto de eso, ya lo tratas

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo validando con una expresion regular:

1. la funcion `preg_match_all()` devuelve todas las coincidencias
   encontradas en un string en forma de arreglo
2. la function `preg_match_all()` recibe de 3 argumentos "la expresion
   a validar","texto de entrada" y "variable de salida"

codigo ejemplo:

```
<?php

$entrada="@bryro esta ayudando a @carlos, Gracias";
preg_match_all('/\@[A-Za-z]+/', $entrada,$salida_array);
$salida_array= $salida_array[0]; // obtenemos la posicion 1
  foreach($salida_array as $salida){ // hacemos un loop para todos los resultados
    echo $salida."<br>"; // imprimimos
  }
?>
```

Comment: gracias me funciono perfecto  , saludos y bendiciones